# Rendering an image in material UI appbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, appbar

I am trying to display a brand name/logo in the start of my appbar (Material-UI) but for some reason its not getting displayed.
Please help.

```
<AppBar elevation={0} >
        <Toolbar className={classes.nav}>
        <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
        <img src="../Components/fiad_logo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
      </IconButton>
        <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have to import it at the top of your file, something like this:

```
import logo from '../Components/fiad_logo.jpg'
```

Comment: This gives me the path location of the image file rather than the image.